# Creating a cross platform c++ touch manager. Passing Objective-c objects in c++ involved code

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, uikit

So I am trying to create a multitouch class that can be used cross platform (iOS, Android, etc). The goal is that the engine does not need to know the platform in order to get updated touch data.

Right now I am doing the general design and am specifically implementing the iOS side. The Android etc side will come much later.

In order to do this I am trying to use the delegation pattern. There are really only two interface items.

There is a method update(float dt) to be called on each new frame with the dt. This method then will return a c++ struct of information about all the touches or perhaps set a property that can be accessed. I am not sure.

On the iOS side the only other function that needs to be called from outside is touchesDown which passes in a NSSet* of the UITouches and the UIView that they are in.

Here is the design I am working with thus far

```
Multitouch\
    PlatformTouchManager.h (C++ Abstract Class with Update)
    iOS\
        iOSMultiTouch.cpp (Objective-c++)
        iOSMultiTouch.hpp (Objective-c++ Class inheriting PlatformTouchManager)
    MultTouch.cpp (C++)
    MultiTouch.h (C++ class)
```

Here is PlatformTouchManager.h

```
#define MAX_TOUCHES 5
#define PLATFORM_iOS
//#define PLATFORM_ANDROID

class PlatformTouchManager {
public:
    // Update All The Events
    virtual void update(float time) = 0;
};
```

And of course Multitouch.h

```
class Multitouch {
private:
    PlatformTouchManager* manager;
public:
    Multitouch() {
#ifdef PLATFORM_iOS
        manager = new iOSMultiTouch();
#endif
    }
    ~Multitouch() {
        delete manager;
    }

    Multitouch(const Multitouch&) = delete;

    void update(float dt);

    void* getManager() {
        return manager;
    }
};
```

And finally iOSMultiTouch.hpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../PlatformTouchManager.h"
#include <set>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

class iOSMultiTouch: public PlatformTouchManager {
public:
    // Initializer
    iOSMultiTouch();

    // Destructor
    ~iOSMultiTouch();

    // Update All The Events
    void update(float time);

    // Touch Down Set
    void touchesDown(id<NSSet> set, id<UIView> view);
};
```

It may be worth noting that this code is included by MultiTouch.h (c++) and my native view code which is objective-c++.

The cross platform engine thus creates a Multitouch object, keeps a reference and every frame calls update.

I am imagining that then iOS UIView will get the `Multitouch*` from the cross platform engine. Cast it into a `iOSMultiTouch*` object and call `touchesDown:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(IUView *)view` on the delegate.

I am having a serious problem doing this.

If I try to import UIKit inside iOSMUltiTouch.hpp it causes build chaos so it would appear I can only import it inside of the source file. Therefore my touch down method needs to be void `touchesDown(void* touches, void* view);.`

The problem is then implementing this as when I try to cast these `void*` pointers into their proper types I get the warning `Cast of C pointer type void* to objective-c pointer type id requires a bridged cast`.

I understand that there are some ARC concerns here as ARC cannot track such things when casted into a primitive pointer but how do I get around this?

iOSTouchManager does indeed need to hold a strong reference to the UITouch objects up until after the frame the touch is released.

How do I implement this cast? Is there a different way I should be designing my classes to make this easier?

For those of you who were wondering these are the errors that pop up should you import uikit from iOSMultiTouch.hpp

```
Parse Issue

Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:512:1: Expected unqualified-id
../Multitouch/MultiTouch.cpp:9:10: In file included from ../Multitouch/MultiTouch.cpp:9:
../Multitouch/MultiTouch.h:15:10: In file included from ../Multitouch/MultiTouch.h:15:
../Multitouch/iOS/iOSMultiTouch.hpp:15:9: In file included from ../Multitouch/iOS/iOSMultiTouch.hpp:15:
Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:9: In file included from Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8:9: In file included from Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8:

Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:9:1: Expected unqualified-id
../Multitouch/MultiTouch.cpp:9:10: In file included from ../Multitouch/MultiTouch.cpp:9:
../Multitouch/MultiTouch.h:15:10: In file included from ../Multitouch/MultiTouch.h:15:
../Multitouch/iOS/iOSMultiTouch.hpp:15:9: In file included from ../Multitouch/iOS/iOSMultiTouch.hpp:15:
Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:9: In file included from Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:9: In file included from Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:5:9: In file included from Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:5:
Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:8:9: In file included from Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:8:

Semantic Issues

Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:514:9: Unknown type name 'NSString'
../Multitouch/MultiTouch.cpp:9:10: In file included from ../Multitouch/MultiTouch.cpp:9:
../Multitouch/MultiTouch.h:15:10: In file included from ../Multitouch/MultiTouch.h:15:
../Multitouch/iOS/iOSMultiTouch.hpp:15:9: In file included from ../Multitouch/iOS/iOSMultiTouch.hpp:15:
Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:9: In file included from Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:8:
Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8:9: In file included from Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8:
```

Comment: Throwing away C++'s strong type system by using `void` pointers clearly isn't the right way. I suggest to solve the root issue instead: _"If I try to import UIKit inside iOSMUltiTouch.hpp it causes build chaos so it would appear I can only import it inside of the source file."_ -- what exactly does "build chaos" mean?

Comment: I get a ton of errors in a bunch of iOS frameworks until the compiler stops

Comment: These should be included in your question. Maybe not 100s of similar messages, but the first few to get an idea of what went wrong.

Comment: @zett42 updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

You got ton of errors because you imported iOS framework (`UIKit`) inside a C++ file (`iOSMultiTouch.cpp`).

### Solution

For implementation files which you need to import iOS frameworks to, you have to use `.mm` instead of `.cpp` extension. `.cpp` is C++ extension, not Objective-C++ extension.

In this case, you need to rename `iOSMultiTouch.cpp` to `iOSMultiTouch.mm`. Replace `void *` with Objective-C pointers and it will work as expected.

---

`Utils.h` will keep nothing related to Objective-C and can be used anywhere. `Utils.mm` is used to work with Objective-C parts.

**Utils.h**

```
PlatformTouchManager* GetIOSTouchManager();
```

**Utils.mm**

```
#include "Utils.h"
#include "iOSMultiTouch.hpp"

PlatformTouchManager* GetIOSTouchManager() {
  return new iOSMultiTouch();
};
```

**Multitouch.h**

```
#include "Utils.h"
// Other include

class Multitouch {
  private:
  PlatformTouchManager* manager;
  public:
  Multitouch() {
#ifdef PLATFORM_iOS
    manager = GetIOSTouchManager();
#endif
  }
  ~Multitouch() {
    delete manager;
  }

  Multitouch(const Multitouch&) = delete;

  void update(float dt);

  PlatformTouchManager* getManager() {
    return manager;
  }
};
```

Comment: After doing this the header having a .hpp extension and the footer having a .mm extension I still get the same build errors. I `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` and have the code as shown in the updated question.

Comment: It's because you imported `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` in `iOSMultiTouch.hpp`. `iOSMultiTouch.hpp` is imported in `MultiTouch.h`. `MultiTouch.h` is imported in `MultiTouch.cpp`. It's same as you import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` in `MultiTouch.cpp`. The problem happens again. You need to make sure all implementation files which uses iOS frameworks have `.mm` extension.

Comment: MultiTouch.cpp is cross platform code that needs to be in pure c++ so that later it can be compiled for the android version with an AndroidMultiTouch.hpp file created

Comment: That's why you need to move `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` to implementation file (`iOSMultiTouch.mm`), not in header file.

Comment: Then how do I pass my NSSet of UITouch objects and UIView into iOSMultiTouch.mm while properly using ARC? I need to hold a strong reference on UITouch objects so I control when they become null (I might query their position the frame after they are lifted)

Comment: You can use utils files to avoid this situation. It will separate Objective-C and C++. Utils.h file will keep nothing related to Objective-C and can be used anywhere. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Oh that is clever! I am still having a few issues. Currently in MultiTouch.h I am getting unknown type name GetIOSTouchManager() compiler error is there something I need to do to make that function public outside of its file? Also how will MultiTouch.h know about the deconstructor of iOSMultiTouch?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to make it public. I think you are having compiler error because of where you place `Utils.h` file. Maybe it's `#include "iOS/Utils.h"` if `Utils.h` is inside `iOS` folder. About destructor, you can define virtual destructor in `PlatformTouchManager` interface and override it in `iOSMultiTouch`.

Comment: Thats what I thought too but I confirmed that in XCode as well as the actual folder that Utils.h and .mm are in the iOS folder and that my import does indeed start with iOS. Utils.mm is also included in compile sources. Oddly enough the error has 2 attached notes that say "in file included from _" listing two engine files (The engine header and another internal c++ source file that imports engine) not sure why they are listed

Comment: First of all, let move these 2 files to somewhere else where project can build. Make sure we are going right way and after that you can try to move files to iOS folder again. If it still shows error, you should attach the error log to question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179929/discussion-between-j-doe-and-trungduc).